# Invertible function that randomizes order

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, cryptography, permutations, randomness

I am looking for an invertible discrete function $f:\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\} \to \{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ for some given integer $n$.  I want $f(0),f(1),\dots,f(n-1)$ to return all the integers in range $[0..n)$ exactly once, but in a "messy", random-seeming arrangement.  I anticipate that $n$ will be not bigger than $2^{30}$.

I thought about finding a generator for the group `<Zn,*>`, but I'm not sure if it would work for any given $n$ (would it?).  Any other ideas?

Comment: If $n$ is a prime then you can try $ax^{-1} + b$, where $0^{-1} = 0$.

Comment: nothing garauntees me that n is prime... need a solution for any n, and i also didnt really see hows the suggested solution fit the needs... but thanks for trying :)

Comment: Approximately how large is $n$? Which algorithms are practical depends on the order of magnitude.

Comment: n can be any integer most likely not bigger then 2^30, if it helps 2^20 would also be nice.

Comment: Would [keyed families](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/sr.html) work? ​ If needed, one could probably come up with a sort-of-"canonical" [PRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family) and key. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: (Note: ​ ​ ​ For constructions as described in my previous comment, knowledge of the key makes the inverse just as easy to evaluate. ​ If you're after [onewayness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function), then you should say so.) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Feistel network.

Comment: If I am not wrong, are you looking for a pseudo random permutation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, What i do isnt for encryption and i was looking for something quick and simple,  what i did was finding the highest prime p that is smaller than n and a generator g in the group `<Z_p,*>` , and used the following f :

```
f(i) = (g^i)modp - 1 if i<n, i otherwise.
```

I know that the last n-p images are in order but oh well...

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem that you listed in the question, because the resulting map is not a bijection from $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$ to $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$.  For instance, suppose $n=3$, so $p=2$, and $g=1$; then your function is $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 0$, $f(2) = 0$.  That's not a bijection.  Or, suppose $n=4$, so $p=3$, and $g=2$; then your function is $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$, $f(2) = 0$, $f(3) = 1$; again, not a bijection.  If you meant `i<p` instead of `i<n`, it's still not a bijection; consider the same parameters.

Comment: the group is <Z_p,*> not <Z_p,+>, so g you mentioned is not a generator edited my answer

Comment: I think you haven't understood my comment, or you are confused about the definition of generator.  $g=2$ certainly is a generator for the multiplicative group of integers modulo $p=3$, i.e., for the group $\mathbb{Z}_3^*$.  (And $g=1$ is a generator for the multiplicative group of integers modulo $p=2$.)

Comment: g=1 is not a generator for p=2, you cant create 0 using 1^i, anyhow, the solution i wrote works for me, so thanks.

Comment: 0 is not an element of the multiplicative group, as it is not invertible: $\mathbb{Z}_p^*= (\{1,2,3,\dots,p-1\},\times)$.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for a pseudorandom permutation on the set $\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$.  In cryptography, this has been studied under the (counter-intuitive) name "[format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption)".  There are a number of constructions you could use for your purposes.

There's a bunch of research literature on the problem, with different schemes that are optimized for different values of $n$.  You can also find some summaries on Cryptography.SE.

I recommend you start by reading the question and the answers at [Lazily computing a random permutation of the positive integers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29822/755) and [Encrypting a 180-bit plaintext into a 180 bit ciphertext with a 128-bit block cipher](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/47775/755) and [What are the examples of the easily computable "wild" permutations?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/41124/755).